# My logic app isn't delivering emails after my adf pipeline failed

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-logic-apps

My web activity is not delivering emails to mailbox after my ADF pipeline run failed, What can be possible reasons for it? can someone provide me solutions

I tried creating sample pipeline with sample notebook, but didn't triggered to my email.

Comment: are you using logic app to trigger emails after ADF pipeline run failed? It would be helpful if you provide more details.

Comment: Yes, I am using logic app to trigger my emails

Comment: Too hard to help, you’ve provided no insight that helps us understand what could be wrong.

Comment: Please Let me know what type insights to provide

Comment: Can you please add images of your pipeline and error if you are facing any?

Comment: I have added image of my pipeline, and i am not getting any errors but not receving emails

Answer (score 0):

You need to add role assignment for Azure data factory and assign contributor role from logic app. This could be one of the reasons that logic app not sending mails after an ADF pipeline run fails.
There is an alternative approach that you try to achieve this scenario.

- Created a sample data factory pipeline as shown below,
  [image]
- In ADF monitor, added new alert as shown below,
  [image]
- Configured an action existing action group that will trigger logic app and send email,
  [image]
- Configured logic app as action in action group,
  [image]
- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- Whenever ADF pipeline run fails, logic app will be triggered through action group and email will be send as per the configuration.
- ADF pipeline failed as shown below and received mail,
  [image]
  [image]